# Hash Table Obscure Failure

Tags: java, hash, hashmap, hashtable, chaining

I have to create a relational database management system for one of my uni classes. I am using chaining, and am having an obscure problem. When I run my JUnit tester by having it put(), remove(), and get() keys with a length of 2 characters, everything runs as it should. When I begin putting key-value pairs with a key length of 3 or more, everything instantly fails.

At first, I thought it was my hash function, but after many hours I've made no improvements. Here is what it looks like. the instructor's module specifications only require us to create a hash function algorithm for string objects. Otherwise, we call the Object class's hashCode().

```
    public int myHash(K key){

        int hash = 0;

        if(key instanceof String){
            for (int i = 0; i < key.toString().length(); i++) {
                hash += hash*31+ key.toString().charAt(i);
            }

            if(hash < 0){
                hash = (int)Math.abs(hash);
            }
        }else{
            Object obj = (Object) key;
            hash = key.hashCode();
        }
        System.err.println(hash % size);
        return hash;    

    }
```

I ran many tests with debugging lines, and it seems that my methods reach the correct index location, but return null instead of the desired value. Again, my put(K key, V value), remove(K key), get(K key) all work for keys with a key length of 2, but 'break' at longer key lengths. Any ideas as to why this is?

(Edit: spelling/grammatical errors)

Comment: The hash function you've shown looks fine to me; I don't see a problem with it.  I suspect the problem is with how you are using this hash function. 
 Would it be possible to edit your question and add, say, a JUnit test that passes and one that fails, and the code these tests call?

Comment: Can you add a junit test that shows the problem?